# Is it possible to access the iBooks PDF files from my custom application

Tags: ios, icloud, ibooks

I read and read Blogs in google but still could not draw the conclusion regarding,Can we upload the iBooks PDF files through the custom application? some says "No, there is currently no way to access this information"

I have a application like Gmail. now i want to send mail that may be image or PDF files. I can easily attach the Image files from my phone but could not excess the PDF from my iBooks.

Is it mandatory that PDF must be uploaded through iClouds?
Hope i could draw the conclusion regarding this Problem,from here..